# Get the "Key" for a strongly typed model in the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So I am trying to do get the key for a model object in the controller so that I can add a `AddModelError` to it.

In my view I use

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
```

Whats the equivalent code to get the `Key` name to add in the controller so it attaches to this ValidationMessage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "the email is invalid");
```

But usually that's not something you should be doing manually in your controller but you should be using a validator. For example you could decorate this Email property with some validation data annotation attribute or if you are like me use [FluentValidation.NET](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation) => this way you shouldn't be asking yourself questions about keys but focus on the actual validation logic.

Comment: Is the Key always going to be the name? I thought this was generated so wasn't always guaranteed to be the object name?

Comment: It is always equal to the field name. Just be cautious because if you rename the field (even using ReSharper), it will not update this string because they only match by coincidence. Luckily, I believe that using an unknown key won't have any adverse effects (like making your page throw Exceptions), it is the equivalent of using `null`.

Answer (score 22):

You can use an extension that does the same as the HtmlHelpers, and that will work for nested properties:

```
public static class ModelStateExtensions
{
  public static void AddModelError<TModel>(this ModelStateDictionary dictionary, Expression<Func<TModel, object>> expression, string errorMessage)
  {
    dictionary.AddModelError(ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression), errorMessage);
  }
}
```

So you can use it like this:

```
ModelState.AddModelError<TModel>(i => i.Person.Name, "test");
```

equivalent to

```
ModelState.AddModelError("Person.Name", "test");
```

It will generate the same Id as the Html. In the MVC source they do some extra sanitizing, but with normal names that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Just ran into an error using this. If the property is a struct than the expression looks like Convert(property) because the expression returns an object. In that case the expression text evaluates to an empty string. I recommend changing the function into public static void AddModelError<TModel,TValue>(this ModelStateDictionary dictionary, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, string errorMessage) and calling it like ModelState.AddModelError((TModel i) => i.Person.Name, "test")