# ASP.net MVC 4 validate if number is contained in a set of valid values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to set a validation rule for a int value in my model.

The value can only be 1 , 2  or 4. so i cant use a range validation rule. How should i validate if the number is valid ?

i could not find anything but range, so unfortunately i don't have anything yet.

Comment: What do you have so far? Can you show the code?

Comment: You can write your own validation attributes, implement IValidatableObject, or use a regular expression.  Those are all the approaches I can think of, anyway.

Comment: Also, you can validate the object in your POST function (if you have such one) or I think there is a way to validate this in javascript - but the its vulnerable.

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
[RegularExpression("[124]", ErrorMessage = "Value must be 1, 2 or 4")]
public int Value{ get; set; }
```

Comment: Nice and simple great !

Answer (score 1):

The `RegularExpression` validator with a valid set of values [124] is the obvious option.

However, i have found an interesting alternative that has definitely better performance than the RegularExpression validator. The idea is to use an `EnumDataType` validator with valid values for the integers:

```
[EnumDataType(typeof(ValidValues), ErrorMessage = "Valid values are 1,2,4")]
public int ReqValue { get; set; }

public enum ValidValues
{
    First = 1,
    Second = 2,
    Fourth = 4
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your project: [Get the "Key" for a strongly typed model in the controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12010511/get-the-key-for-a-strongly-typed-model-in-the-controller/12011305#12011305)

Then add a method which performs the validation, say, `void Validate(YourModelType model)`.

Finally, in your POST action, put something like this:

```
Validate(model);

if (ModelState.IsValid) {
    //valid, do whatever actions you need
    return RedirectToAction("whatever");
}

return View(model); //show the page again
```

Comment: Keep in mind, this does not enable any client-side validation. I tend to use this method for more complex things that are database-dependent. It just also happens to be simple enough for what you want, while still integrating with MVC's server-side validation.