# Get modelstate key for viewmodel property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, modelstate

I have an add product form which depends upon the user having added categories, product types etc. previously. Rather than let them complete the form, and then realise that they can't submit it, I want to show an error when the form first loads.

I want to add this error to the modelstate against the appropriate property - so my question is how can I get the modelstate key name for that property?

**Code**

```
    Model.Step1.PopulateData(_productTypeSvc.GetList(), _websiteSvc.GetMaximumNumberOfProductImages(HttpContext.Request.Url.Host));
    Model.Title = "Add A Product - Step 1: The Basics";
    if (Model.Step1.ProductTypes.IsNullOrEmpty())
    {
        //Rather than string.Empty, I want to programmatically get the correct key to add the error to..
        //E.g. if it were the view - HtmlHelper.NameFor(m => m.Step1.ProductTypeID)
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Please add at least one product type before adding products.");
    }
```

I know I can dummy the HtmlHelper object, but I'd rather avoid this and wondered if there is a better way?

Comment: Its just the fully qualified name of the property - `ModelState.AddModelError("Step1.ProductTypeID", "Please ...");`

Comment: I know, but I want to have it strongly typed, not a loose string.

Comment: There is no overload for it. You can create an extension method and implement this expression with reflection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found an appropriate extension in MVC:

```
System.Web.Mvc.ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(LambdaExpression expression);
```

[MSDN Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.expressionhelper.getexpressiontext%28v=vs.118%29.aspx).

Thanks anyway guys.

Update:

```
public static string GetPropertyName<TModel, TValue>(this TModel model, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> propertySelector)
{
     return ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(propertySelector);
}
```

Then use the extension:

```
ModelState.AddModelError(Model.GetPropertyName(m => m.Step1.ProductTypeID), "Please add at least one product type before adding products.");
```

Comment: Ok, but how did you use the `ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText` in this case?

Comment: @ctekse, I have updated the answer I gave with my implementation - which was to create an extension in the System.Web.Mvc namespace utilising the built-in expressionhelper. Hope this helps.

Comment: Similar [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12010511/get-the-key-for-a-strongly-typed-model-in-the-controller), this one is extension for AddModelError. Not my post btw.